# (Django) Signal isn't working but it works in the shell

Tags: python, django, signals

I have a signal that runs post_save when a new Student is created that goes through their currently enrolled courses and assigns them an instance of the courses' assignments (for scoring).

In `users/signals.py`:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Student)
def save_student_assignments(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        all_courses = instance.enrolled_courses.all()
        assignments = Assignment.objects.filter(session_link__in=all_courses)
        for assignment in assignments:
            StudentAssignment.objects.create(student=instance, assignment=assignment)
```

I have already been in `users/apps.py` to import the signal.

If I run this exact code in the shell, it will create the StudentAssignment objects and they'll show up for the user.

What am I missing here that's not making the signal fire like it should?

Answer (score 0):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Student)
def create_student_assignments(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            all_courses = instance.enrolled_courses.all()
            assignments = Assignment.objects.filter(session_link__in=all_courses)
            for assignment in assignments:
                StudentAssignment.objects.create(student=instance, assignment=assignment)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Student)
def save_student_assignments(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.studentassignment.save()
```

If you have a related_name attribute on the foreignkey change `instance.studentassignment.save()` to instance.`related_name`.save()

heres a tutorial: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the save_student_assignments is doing since I already used the StudentAssignment.objects.create() method above. So when I create a new Student and enroll them in classes, it does create them in the database. If I go into the django shell and run those commands I posted, it works fine and their StudentAssignment objects are populated for them. It just doesn't trigger in the signal for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what went wrong, because when I created a new Student and enrolled them in courses, it would enroll them, but the post_save never ran how I wanted it to. I did however get a new solution that worked for me:

Instead of this:

```
def create_new_student(request):
    form = NewStudentForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Student created!')
    else:
        form = NewStudentForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'users/new_student_form.html', {'form': form})
```

I added this:

```
def create_new_student(request):
    form = NewStudentForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        student = form.cleaned_data['user']
        student=Student.objects.get(user=student)
        all_courses = form.cleaned_data['enrolled_courses'].all()
        assignments = Assignment.objects.filter(session_link__in=all_courses)
        for assignment in assignments:
            StudentAssignment.objects.create(student=student, assignment=assignment)
        messages.success(request, 'Student created!')
    else:
        form = NewStudentForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'users/new_student_form.html', {'form': form})
```

This comes off as a bit hacky to me, so if someone can figure out why my signal wasn't working before, I'd love to clean this up, but I figured out what I needed.